# Redirecting to another website using Redirect::to()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, redirect

When I use `Redirect::to($url)` this is the result:

```
http://localhost/http://mysite.com/foo/bar.html
```

But when I use `Redirect::to('http://google.com')` it goes to google just fine, any guess what my problem is?

Answer (score 25):

You need to provide fully qualifying URL to `Redirect::to()` method, otherwise application base URL is prepended.

```
$url = 'www.google.com';
// redirects to http://localhost:8888/www.google.com
return Redirect::to($url);

$url = 'http://google.com';
// redirects to http://google.com
return Redirect::to($url);
```

Comment: I tried redirecting using the value i got like this,  redirect::to('http://mysite.com/foo/bar.html')with(http://) and it worked, anyway, $url = $object->url; is there a problem with properties

Comment: What does `$object->url` stand for? Maybe `url` property does not return URL with `http` protocol. Just do `dd($object->url)` to see the value.

Answer (score 4):

To redirect to an external domain, use a fully qualified url such as tiqeet.com

in your controller, call a return Redirect::intended("your fully qualified domain");

hope it works for you. Used it in laravel 4.0

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('/', function () {

  $url = 'YOUR DOMAIN NAME HERE';  //DOMAIN NAME MUST BE LIKE THIS : https://www.google.com/

  return Redirect::to($url);

});
```

In I'm using Laravel 5.5 only for API's so in web route file i redirected to my domain name if any one tried to open the API domain name its redirected to my same domain

Comment: better read that comment also properly  which i entered before commenting